# Alembic migrations in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic

I have a FastAPI application which uses ormar orm and alembic for db migrations.

When I migrate my changes to db everything is working but alembic versions that stored inside my container alembic directory won't be stored in my local alembic directory.

That's why when I do `docker-compose up --build` and when I migrate changes again I get `Can't locate revision identified by ...` error.

How can I connect the alembic directory in my container to my local alembic directory?

Comment: What happens if you upgrade head right away? (instead of running revision)